# Rewriting matrix multiplication

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix multiplication in Matlab that goes as follows

$$\hat{W} = N W N^{T},$$ where $^T$ means a transposition. $N$ is an incidence matrix with the dimensions m x n and
W = diag(G), where G is a 1 x n row vector, which makes diag(G) n x n. So basically, when I have a large vector G, e.g. more than 1000 elements I run out of memory because I have a diagonal matrix with n x n elements and most of them are zero. Is there a way to write such multiplication in a more efficient way in Matlab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
N * (G' .* N')
```

A few releases ago Matlab introduced *singleton expansion*: in expressions like the one in parentheses the $n\times 1$ matrix `G'` is "upgraded" to an $n\times m$ matrix (with all columns equal) before the elementwise product.

This new feature gives a cleaner way to implement some tricks that previously required `bsxfun`.

Comment: This is a nice option as well. Is there a way to represent my other comment. I thank you for your reply.

Comment: @Bakr The one with `A + diag(G)`? There would be a couple of minor improvements, but in that case the addition is the least of your problems; it is the linear system solution that will take the most CPU time.

Answer (score 2):

Solution slightly modified from [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/87629-efficiently-multiplying-diagonal-and-general-matrices)

`W2 = N * bsxfun(@times, N, G).';`

This works for `N` of size `m x n`, and `G` of size `1 x n`.

Comment: This is perfect thank you. I searched so much for an answer but I didn't find anything

Comment: Actually I have one more question. I have another formula with $[A - diag(G)]^{-1}[A + diag(G)]$. Is there an alternative for this formula as well?

Comment: Forgot to say that A is a nxn matrix

Comment: @Bakr No, I don't think there's much you can do with that.